Make array type with generic objects and nested in typescript
I want make type of array like this (k1 and k2 must be same type)
[
  {k1: 'str', k2: 'str'},
  {k1: 12, k2: 23},
  [
    {k1: 'hh', k2: 'kk'}, 
    {k1: true, k2: false}
  ]
]

I try with type
type Test<T extends readonly any[]> = [...({ [K in keyof T]: { k1: T[K], k2: NoInfer<T[K]> } })]

But it doesn't apply to nested array (ex playground link)

How did you make Test work for non-nested arrays? A helper function or something? Could you make a [mre] we can use to get working on it?

Here you are link

Are you looking for arbitrarily nested? Are we supposed to special-case string, number, and boolean?  How do we determine things are "the same type"? Would {k1: string | number, k2: string | number} work for you somehow? Note that boolean is true | false so {k1: true, k2: false} are "different types". It's hard to get TS to pay attention to the nested structure of an array without using as const, in which case you get types like {k1: "x", k2: "y"} and k2 isn't assignable to k1.

• Please provide your [mre] as plaintext and not just as a link. • Right now I have this approach which involves a lot of jumping through hoops. And it's fragile. I'd say this is isn't something you really want to enforce purely at the type level, and you'd be better off just forcing your objects to be constructed individually like this. I could write up an answer if that meets your needs, but it's not fun.
